# How to put Image into directory imagejpeg()?

Tags: php, html

Okay I have this code that crops the image and display it, what I wanted to do is instead of just displaying it I wanted to save the image in a folder here is the full code

```
    <?php
/*
 * Crop-to-fit PHP-GD
 * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2009/04/crop-to-fit-image-using-aspphp.html
 *
 * Resize and center crop an arbitrary size image to fixed width and height
 * e.g. convert a large portrait/landscape image to a small square thumbnail
 */

define('DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH', 512);
define('DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT', 289);

$source_path = $_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name'];

/*
 * Add file validation code here
 */

list($source_width, $source_height, $source_type) = getimagesize($source_path);

switch ($source_type) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $source_gdim = imagecreatefromgif($source_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $source_gdim = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $source_gdim = imagecreatefrompng($source_path);
        break;
}

$source_aspect_ratio = $source_width / $source_height;
$desired_aspect_ratio = DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH / DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT;

if ($source_aspect_ratio > $desired_aspect_ratio) {
    /*
     * Triggered when source image is wider
     */
    $temp_height = DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
    $temp_width = ( int ) (DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT * $source_aspect_ratio);
} else {
    /*
     * Triggered otherwise (i.e. source image is similar or taller)
     */
    $temp_width = DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH;
    $temp_height = ( int ) (DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH / $source_aspect_ratio);
}

/*
 * Resize the image into a temporary GD image
 */

$temp_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor($temp_width, $temp_height);
imagecopyresampled(
    $temp_gdim,
    $source_gdim,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    $temp_width, $temp_height,
    $source_width, $source_height
);

/*
 * Copy cropped region from temporary image into the desired GD image
 */

$x0 = ($temp_width - DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH) / 2;
$y0 = ($temp_height - DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT) / 2;
$desired_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor(DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH, DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
imagecopy(
    $desired_gdim,
    $temp_gdim,
    0, 0,
    $x0, $y0,
    DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH, DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT
);

/*
 * Render the image
 * Alternatively, you can save the image in file-system or database
 */
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg( $desired_gdim );
/*
 * Add clean-up code here
 */
?>
```

My problem is in the last line where `imagejpeg( $desired_gdim );` 
should be `imagejpeg( $desired_gdim, 'img/whatever-filename.jpg' );`

But the image is not even shown in the browser and it is not sent to the directory, also if I want to insert it with the file name I already uploaded it with same thing happen just an the small icon of broken image

Comment: header(content-type : image/jpeg), are you trying to show the pic, for saving just use `imagejpeg ( $desired_gdim $filename )`

Comment: Define "not working". What is happening or not happening? Do you get any errors? Have you checked?

Comment: remove header(content-type), it is used to render not to save. Regards

Comment: What does _it is not working_ mean? Do you receive any kind of error message?

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not a well formulated question. This calls for basic debugging first. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Comment: The image is not even shown in the browser and it is not sent to the directory, just the small icon of broken image

Comment: @deceze Yes it is showing a broken icon of an image

Comment: @X-Factor I tried that but still it is sending me to the broken icon of an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose between the two - either show the image or save it to directory. You cant do both.

```
imagejpeg($gd_object); //shows the image, requires content-type to be image/jpeg

imagejpeg($gd_object, $filepath); //saves the image, to $filepath
```

You can try to save the image and then redirect the use to the image if you want to show it.

```
imagejpeg($gd_object, $filepath);
header("Location: $filepath");
```

Answer (score 0):

change your path 'img/whatever-filename.jpg' to document root directory you can get using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and append your desire path. e.g $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/whatever-filename.jpg';